# How can insert Drop Down Box values into cross reference Table?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC framework, I've created a view to add a Mentee to my mentee database table. Although i'm able to to enter all info related to my mentee I can't seem to figure out how to take whatever value is chosen from my school drop down box and enter the id value to the cross reference table mentee_school **Note: There are already values in the school drop down table**. For example:

[image]

**Table Relationship:**

[image]

**Mentee View Model:**

```
 public class MenteeViewModel
{

    public mentee mentee { get; set; }
    public guardian guardian { get; set; }
    public address address { get; set; }        
    public email email { get; set; }
    public user users { get; set; }
    public phnumber phnumber { get; set; }                
    public econtact econtact { get; set; }        
    [Display(Name = "School System")]
    public int SelectedSSystemId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SSystemItems { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "School")]
    public int SelectedSchoolId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SchoolItems { get; set; }      

}
```

**Mentee View:**

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedSchoolId)
    </div>        
    <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSchoolId,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.school_ids, "--Select One--")
    </div>
```

**Mentee Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ViewModels.MenteeViewModel menteeViewModel )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            menteeViewModel.mentee.addresses.Add(menteeViewModel.address);
            menteeViewModel.mentee.guardians.Add(menteeViewModel.guardian);
            menteeViewModel.mentee.econtacts.Add(menteeViewModel.econtact);
            menteeViewModel.mentee.emails.Add(menteeViewModel.email);

            //Below statement doesn't work with current model
            menteeViewModel.mentee.schools.Add(menteeViewModel.SelectedSchoolId);

            db.mentees.Add(menteeViewModel.mentee);               
            db.SaveChanges();




            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        return Create();
    }
```

My question is how can persist the value of the the selected school in the drop down box and the mentee id to the mentee_school cross reference table?

Comment: I've tried my hand at this and i'm stumped. If there is any other question/answer post similar to this, it would be greatly appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go another route. I added a schoolId column to my "Mentees" table so that whenever I add a mentee I update that value with the SelectedSchoolID.

```
menteeViewModel.mentee.schoolId = menteeViewModel.SelectedSchoolId.ToString();
db.mentees.Add(menteeViewModel.mentee);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks anyway!